# What is the layout style for sites like GrooveShark called?

Tags: website-design, style, website-templates

I don't need to know the artistic style but instead the style name for single page  application like webpages.  They have dynamic height and width with no scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

This is liquid layout that varies according to the size of the browser With the help of jquery. and its Minimalist Design also IMO.

- [What UI toolkits/frameworks were used in Grooveshark's new
  HTML-based UI?](http://www.quora.com/What-UI-toolkits-frameworks-were-used-in-Groovesharks-new-HTML-based-UI)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Web sites designed to adapt to the size of the screen (or browser window) are said to use [Responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). The same code is used to display the interface on computers, tablets and phones, but the size and position of elements is changed. Sometimes elements are hidden on smaller screens, and generally vertical scrolling is allowed.